# Issue with Windows service/Application uninstall

Tags: service, windows-7, wix

I have an application A running on a Windows 7 machine..which has an exe file A.exe. This application runs as a service. Now, when I uninstall the app with the Windows services window still open and then install the application back, the service name A does not show up in the Services window at all...unless I restart the PC.

THings work well when I do not have the Services window open....the app gets installed properly and is also added as a service in the services window.

I read in some forum that Windows Vista or 2000 had an issue where Windows services would not get updated properly if we leave the services window open during uninstallation...not sure if we have somerhing similar in Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The service control manager (aka: SCM) can be locked much in the same way that files and folders can be locked. When locked, the resources cannot be updated in place until whatever is locking them fully releases the resource. Sometimes, it takes a restart to fully kill off whatever locked the resource.

I've seen cases where little tool tray apps held locks on the SCM wreaking all kinds of havoc with installs. If the tool tray app was killed (killed, not closed) the services would install just fine. I did not believe that services.msc caused the same sort of behavior but it sounds like it on your machine.

Comment: So, does it mean the best option is to keep the Services window always closed when you uninstall or install something. Else restart the machine if needed.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing to do. I can't say I ever run installs with services.msc open. Shrug.